# How change __eq__ of class during script execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

class File:
    ### Сlass initialization
    def __init__(self, path, name, size, date):
        self.path = path
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
        self.date = date

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # if self.name == other.name and self.size == other.size and self.date == other.date:
        if self.name == other.name and self.size == other.size:
        # if self.size == other.size and self.date == other.date:
            return True**
```

#### How change (**eq**) of class during script execution?

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # if self.name == other.name and self.size == other.size and self.date == other.date:
        if self.name == other.name and self.size == other.size:
        # if self.size == other.size and self.date == other.date:
        return True
```

Different variants must be triggered when certain conditions occur

Comment: This is an XY problem; changing your `__eq__` method mid-program is almost certainly not the best way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve by doing so.

Comment: I haven't played with it to see if what you're asking is possible, but I think the more correct solution would be to use `__eq__` to route to the different functions depending on the conditions.

Comment: when modification is triggered, on `__eq__` call? it smells like you need a factory pattern.

Comment: Under what conditions do you want the result of `__eq__` to change?

Comment: When I need compare some files by using one code and change only "==". If prog didn't find ",full" duplicate (name, time, size), I need change "==" to check duplicate by time and size. I'm sure we have another way, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is certainly possible:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.x == self.x

foo1 = Foo(1)
foo2 = Foo(2)

print (foo1 == foo2)

def new_eq(self, other):
    return other.x - 1 == self.x

Foo.__eq__ = new_eq

print (foo1 == foo2)
```

Explanation:

`__eq__` is an attribute of the class `Foo`, and it's a function bound to the class (a class method).  You can set the `__eq__` attribute to a new function to replace it.  Note that because this is modifying the class, all instances see a change, including `foo1` and `foo2` that are already instantiated.

All that said, this is a pretty sketchy practice, especially for something like `__eq__`, so I want to say that this is probably not a good solution to your problem, but not knowing what that problem is, I'll just say that if I were to see this sort of thing in code, it would make me rather nervous.

Comment: Thanks. I need compare some files and find duplicates. I understand that it possible to do by another way, but for me (very jujujunior) it was interesting. And sorry for my low lvl English

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping `__eq__` out on the fly, why not use the conditions to determine which case to use when `__eq__` is called?

```
class Foo:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if (self._condition_1):
            return self._eq_condition_1(other)
        elif (self._condition_2):
            return self._eq_condition_2(other)
        else:
            return self._eq_condition_default(other)

    def _eq_condition_1(self, other):
        return True

    def _eq_condition_2(self, other):
        return False

    def _eq_condition_default(self, other):
        return True
```